# Jackson Version with WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: jackson, websphere-8

I've been trying to find a definitive answer on what version of Jackson IBM packages with WebSphere 8.5.5 but so far have come up dry.  There's a jar in the plugins folder called **com.ibm.ws.prereq.jackson.jar** and I wondered what version of Jackson this is.

Could someone shed some light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is on 1.6.2. You can also get this info from MANIFEST.MF under com.ibm.ws.prereq.jackson.jar.

Comment: I was not aware that I could find that information in the MANIFEST as well; thanks for giving me a fish _and_ teaching me how to fish!