# Serialization error when switching from Websphere App Server to Open Liberty

Tags: java, spring, jackson, websphere, open-liberty

I'm moving a java 8 app from WAS 8.5 to Open Liberty 23.   The app runs but gets the exception below when some data is being serialized in one of the REST controllers.  No code or library changes were made.  the only difference is that im trying to now run the app from the eclipse open liberty plugin instead of the myeclipse WAS plugin.

im not clear where to even look for this issue.  It looks like spring is maybe not using the same jackson version?  Note, the same code works fine in WAS. And why would I get an error like this when serializing?

A couple thoughts:

- I'm assuming the servlet jar is different.  I see  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service in the stack trace, which is why I mention this.  I was a little confused about where the servlet jar was coming from with Open Liberty.  the OL eclipse plugin did not seem to include this.
- WAS has parent first class loaders as described here - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=loading-configuring-class-loaders-server.  WAS has some jackson classes  - [Jackson Version with WebSphere 8.5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412784/jackson-version-with-websphere-8-5-5).  I don't think this is the issue because my app has jackson 2.11 & WAS had jackson 1.6.2.  The jackson package names changed between these releases so my app should be using the same jackson classes in both WAS & OL.

Any ideas?

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: com.test.apps.models.image cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer (through reference chain: com.apps.models.Response["data"]->com.apps.models.SearchResults["otherdata"]->com.apps.models.Information["dataGroup"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: com.apps.models.Image cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer (through reference chain: com.apps.models.Response["data"]->com.apps.SearchResults["otherdata"]->com.apps.Information["dataGroup"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:207)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1258)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:193)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:98)
    at com.test.apps.filters.SessionValidationFilter.doFilter(SessionValidationFilter.java:56)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.test.apps.filters.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1002)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1140)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5049)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:314)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1159)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:428)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:566)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:958)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1047)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: com.test.apps.models.image cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer (through reference chain: com.apps.models.Response["data"]->com.apps.models.SearchResults["otherdata"]->com.apps.models.Information["datagroup"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:209)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:180)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:544)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:551)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.se
rialize(BeanSerializer.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1727)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:204)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.apps.models.image cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NumberSerializers$IntegerSerializer.serialize(NumberSerializers.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(IndexedListSerializer.java:118)
```

Answer (score 0):

IBM has an Application Migration Toolkit for Application Binaries (binary scanner). This tool was made to scan applications and create a report on migration issues including a migration from WebSphere 8.5 to Open Liberty. This tool helps with other migration scenarios too such as changing java versions.

By scanning the application with the binary scanner you may get closer to finding the issue that arose from your platform migration (See: *[Migration Toolkit for Application Binaries](http://ibm.biz/WAMT4AppBinaries)*)

See also: *[Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/SSRQNQ/applicationBinaryMigration/overview.html)*